# Progressive Web App Notification When Clearing Tasks/Killing App

Tags: android, google-chrome, notifications, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I've been experimenting with Progressive Web Apps (PWA) and using service workers to create native Notifications on phones (like a Galaxy s7/s8).

All has been working great if the page/PWA is open or in the background/tasks (super slick :D), but one thing I've noticed is that if it is killed via the task manager, the notifications no longer work.

This seems to be the case whether I'm using the web app in the browser or if I add it to home page using the PWA functionality.

Here is a snippet of a simple piece of logic in case it helps:

```
        if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
            navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(serviceWorker) {
                serviceWorker.showNotification('You have new notifications!');
            });
        }
```

**Questions**

1) Is this an inherent limitation of PWA's?

2) Is there a workaround (like auto-starting the app, perhaps)?

Answer (score 1):

> All has been working great if the page/PWA is open or in the background/tasks (super slick :D), but one thing I've noticed is that if it is killed via the task manager, the notifications no longer work.

I beg to differ.  I have created a PWA for a bus app and even if I kill the app, I still receive the notification.

To answer your questions:

1. iOS is the biggest limitation as of the moment.  The idea of having a PWA is to behave and look like an app.  Having push notifications and offline caching is one of the things driving a PWA to be successful and not build an app.
2. There is no such thing as an auto-start.  If the user has landed on the page and the SW has installed properly, it is already "listening" in the background.

Comment: So, could you share some code, please? As I mentioned, my service worker doesn't seem to send notifications when I kill the process/app. You explicitly killed your app and the notifications still work?

Are you using PUSH API in union with notifications? If so, that could be why yours is working.

Comment: I built (this)[https://cbrbuses.firebaseapp.com/].  Follow these steps so you will get the notification: 1); type in 3409; 2) Click on any of the boxes. It will take you to a map; 3) Find the blue pin.  Click on the B Circle where the blue pin is pointing.  You will see a toaster that says that it will notify you.  4) Close the app/browser and wait :)

Take note that you have to watch out for where the B pin is and how far is it from the blue pin or else you will have to wait for a very long time.

Comment: You haven't answered my question - are you using PUSH API in addition to NOtification API? Also, I want to be able to accept and upvote your answer, but I'd like to see a couple things. 1) references for answer #2 and 2) a little bit of important code pieces

Comment: Apologies.  I missed that part.  Base with me also with the terms, I might get it mixed up.  I am using `self.addEventListener('push', function (event) { ... }` in the service worker to receive the notification pushed from the server.  My server is running in expressJS with an NPM module called web-push.  `webPush.sendNotification(pushSubscriptions, payload, options)` is the line of code that sends the notification to the users' endpoint